# How store as JSON the new data inside a trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.5

I try to do as explained in:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

> Auditing values as JSON
>
> For PostgreSQL 9.2, or 9.1 with the fantastic json_91 addon, you can
>   log the old and new values in the table as structured json instead of
>   flat text, giving you much more power to query your audit history.
>   Just change the types of v_old_data, v_new_data, original_data and
>   new_data from TEXT to json, then replace ROW(OLD.*) and ROW(NEW.*)
>   with row_to_json(OLD) and row_to_json(NEW) respectively.

However this get me a error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_log (name text, Action TEXT, data jsonb, OUT RETURNS BOOLEAN)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURNS = true;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_city() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE
v_new_data jsonb;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        v_new_data := row_to_jsonb(NEW);
        EXECUTE add_log('City', 'City.New', v_new_data);
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

INSERT INTO Location (city, state, country) values ('a', 'b' , 'c')
```

It say:

> ERROR:  function row_to_jsonb(location) does not exist

If I put `v_new_data := row_to_jsonb(ROW(NEW));` then I get:

> ERROR:  function row_to_jsonb(record) does not exist

Comment: I try all again and yes, with json it work, but with jsonb not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stated in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) that

> Table 9-42 shows the functions that are available for creating json
>   and jsonb values. (There are no equivalent functions for jsonb, of the
>   row_to_json and array_to_json functions. However, the to_jsonb
>   function supplies much the same functionality as these functions
>   would.)

thus it's `row_to_json` that has to be used. a row_to_jsonb does not exists but `row_to_json` produces the desired result for the `JSONB` type as well.

Answer (score 0):

That [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) article was brilliant to combine with JSON.

Here's an implementation I did using Postgres 14 and JSON, so you don't need the `ROW` anymore.

- I have `updated_by` and `created_by` on all tables that will be audited, so I use that instead of the database user for the `user_id`
- I extract the `id` of the field being modified out into it's own `record_id` field
- I'm not doing this in a separate schema

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION if_modified() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
DECLARE
    v_old_record jsonb;
    v_new_record jsonb;

BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        /** {@link https://stackoverflow.com/q/37824289} */
        v_old_record := row_to_json(OLD);
        v_new_record := row_to_json(NEW);

        INSERT INTO audit_logs (action, table_name, user_id, record_id, old_record, new_record)
        VALUES (TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT, NEW.updated_by, NEW.id::TEXT, v_old_record, v_new_record);

        RETURN NEW;

    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        v_old_record := row_to_json(OLD);

        INSERT INTO audit_logs (action, table_name, record_id, old_record)
        VALUES (TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT, OLD.id::TEXT, v_old_record);

        RETURN OLD;

    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        v_new_record := row_to_json(NEW);

        INSERT INTO audit_logs (action, table_name, user_id, record_id, new_record)
        VALUES (TG_OP, TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT, NEW.created_by, NEW.id::TEXT, v_new_record);

        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        RAISE WARNING '[IF_MODIFIED] - Other action occurred: %, at %', TG_OP, now();

        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION

    WHEN data_exception THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[IF_MODIFIED] - UDF ERROR [DATA EXCEPTION] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;

    WHEN unique_violation THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[IF_MODIFIED] - UDF ERROR [UNIQUE] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[IF_MODIFIED] - UDF ERROR [OTHER] - SQLSTATE: %, SQLERRM: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
        RETURN NULL;
END;

$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Here's the table I create:

```sql
CREATE TABLE audit_logs (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    action TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (action IN ('INSERT', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE')),
    table_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    record_id TEXT,
    old_record jsonb,
    new_record jsonb,
    user_id int,
    created_at timestamp WITH time ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE audit_logs
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_audit_logs_user_id
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(id);

ALTER TABLE audit_logs
ADD CONSTRAINT check_old_record_new_record_not_null
CHECK (
    (old_record IS NOT NULL) OR
    (new_record IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Then an example trigger on the `users` table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER users_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE if_modified();
```